# document.getElementById returns null with use of a variable to pass Id to function onclick

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two searches of a JSON file producing results on two separate parts of the page in two separate divs. The results are produced by for loops, and many hidden divs are created in each of the two results divs, which are displayed by onclick. The id's in div #1 are as "a"+i, where i is the for loop counter. Div #2 is similar with the hidden id's being "aa"+i. Must not have duplicate ID's. The document.getElementById in the function unhyde() is null, if I pass the hidden div's id to display it as thus:

```
function allWriter() {
  var i = "2"; // to simulate one for loop iteration
  var theid = "a"+i;
  var out = '<div onclick="unhyde('+theid+')">John Smith</div>';
  out +='<div id="'+theid+'\" style="display: none;">Read This</div>';
  document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = out;
}

function unhyde (theid) {
  document.getElementById(theid).style.display="block";

<body>
<div onclick="allWriter()">start</div>
<div id="b"></div>
</body>
```

Why? But the following works, but the "a" or "aa" must be hardcoded in the unhyde() function, and I don't want that:

```
function allWriter() {
  var i = "2"; // to simulate one for loop iteration
  var out = '<div onclick=\"unhyde('+i+')">John Smith</div>';
  out +='<div id="a'+i+'" style="display: none;">Read This</div>';
  document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = out;
}

function unhyde (i) {
  document.getElementById('a'+i).style.display="block";
}

<body>
<div onclick="allWriter()">start</div>
<div id="b"></div>
</body>
```

How can I do this by passing the whole id as a variable and use the same unhyde() function regardless of the id? And why the difference in these two examples? I'd rather not use JQuery, but will only if there's no other way.

Comment: If you look at the generated code, you see that it generates `unhyde(a2)`, where you actually want `unhyde("a2")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the generated code for the first example, you see that it generates

```
onlick="unhyde(a2)"
```

I.e. it tries to pass the variable `a2` to the function.   Coincidentally, it exists. It refers to the DOM element with ID `a2`. However, since the value already *is* a DOM element, you cannot pass it to `document.getElementById`, `getElementById` expects a string.

The problem does not exist in the second case because the generated code is `unhyde(2)`, i.e. you are passing the number `2` to the function and `"a" + 2` will result in the *string* `"a2"`, which `getElementById` happily accepts.

To fix the first example you simply have to add quotes, so that you are passing a string instead (`unhyde("a2")`):

```
var out = '<div onclick="unhyde(\''+theid+'\')">John Smith</div>';
```

This is actually a great example why dynamically creating HTML is not a very good approach. A cleaner solution would be to create DOM elements and directly bind the event handler.